# Slider gallery descriptions?

Tags: jquery, css, slider, photo-gallery

I am building a website for a company that offers a lot of different products, so I need to build half a dozen pages with photo galleries. I wrote all the code for a gallery already so all I need to do is copy the HTML on each new page, and change the sources of the images.

However, I also need small descriptions or titles to appear below each picture. Now I could do it like this

```
if (iter === 36) {
        $('.product-title p').html('<p>Photo 36 description</p>');
```

However, considering I have 7 pages with galleries, and about 30 images per gallery, writing it manually like this, one by one, would make my code fucking enormous.

I am wondering is there a simpler way to add titles/descriptions below the gallery that change when the image changes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try through console if work then issue inside your conditions

Comment: You can store description in html data attribute (e.g `data-image-description="Photo 36 description"`. Then in javascript you just need to read that attribute and set the value where you want.

Comment: @tuna that worked like a charm, thank you! I just don't know if I can "accept" your answer, since you wrote it as a comment, if there is a way tell me. or you can just copy it and post it as an answer and I will "accept" it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store image description using html attribute e.g. `data-image-description="Photo 36 description"`.

With this approach you move hardcoded value from JS to HTML. Only think you need to do in JS is read data attribute and set the value where you want.